# How can add an image for submenu(subcategory) in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

I am creating a new module but I want to add images for subcategory in magento2 2.2.

Is there someone to show me how to customize it ? Thanks.

[image: subcategory image]

Comment: Can you be specific about where you want them?

Comment: i added a picture above i want add them like this but i have no idea